# Social network query with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a simple social network implementation with MongoDB. My schema looks like that:

```
User
  _id
  name

Friend
  _id
  user
  friend

Post
  _id
  user
  timestamp
  text
```

I'm trying to use the `aggregate` method to get a list of recent posts from all of my friends, but I would like to group together consecutive posts from the same user. So assuming I have 3 friends and they have the following posts:

```
{"user": "user1", timestamp: 1476200010, text: "hello1"}
{"user": "user2", timestamp: 1476200009, text: "hello2"}
{"user": "user2", timestamp: 1476200008, text: "hello3"}
{"user": "user3", timestamp: 1476200007, text: "hello4"}
{"user": "user2", timestamp: 1476200006, text: "hello5"}
{"user": "user2", timestamp: 1476200005, text: "hello6"}
{"user": "user1", timestamp: 1476200004, text: "hello7"}
{"user": "user1", timestamp: 1476200003, text: "hello8"}
```

I would like as a result, to receive the following:

```
{"user": "user1", timestamp: 1476200010, text: "hello1"}
{"user": "user2", timestamp: 1476200009, text: "hello2"}
{"user": "user3", timestamp: 1476200007, text: "hello4"}
{"user": "user2", timestamp: 1476200006, text: "hello5"}
{"user": "user1", timestamp: 1476200004, text: "hello7"}
```

I'm a bit stuck with my query, any help is appreciated:

```
db.Post.aggregate([
    {$sort: {timestamp: -1}},
    {$lookup: {from: 'Friend', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'friend', as: 'friend'}},
    {$match: {'friend.user': current_user}},
    ???
    {$limit: 100},
])
```

Comment: Regarding this question, `aggregate` doesn't have any support for operations involving neighboring documents so I think you'll need to do the consecutive post pruning in your application code.

Answer (score 0):

In aggregation pipeline, all expressions except accumulators used in the group state do not maintain state i.e. they cannot refer to fields from previous documents. Hence, it is not possible to satisfy this using just a Mongo query. It is better to implement this logic in your application code.